# Find the general solution of the Euler homogenous equation

Tags: integration

"Find the general solution of the Euler homogenous equation
$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2y-x}{2x-y}$."

Through my working out, after introducing a new variable v, where y=xv, I end up having to solve the following:

$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{v-1}dv-\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{1}{v+1}dv$ = $\int\frac{1}{x} dx$

This leads me to the result of

$\frac{3}{2}ln\frac{(v-1)^3}{(v+1)}=ln(x)+c$

Before I begin to rearrange this, to get in terms of y, could someone tell me if I am going in the correct direction because it looks as though I'm going to end up with an $e^c$ term, and I am unsure whether this is correct or not.

Ideally, could someone provide an answer they get from solving this problem - just so I can see if I am going in the correct direction/know if I am correct once I reach an answer? Thank you.

Comment: Shouldn't be $$\frac{1}{2}\ln\frac{(v-1)}{(v+1)^3}=\ln(x)+c$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{v-1}dv-\frac{3}{2}\int\frac{1}{v+1}dv = \int\frac{1}{x} dx$$

Integrating we get,

$$\frac{1}{2}\log{(|v-1|)}-\frac{3}{2}\log{(|v+1|)} = \log{|x|}+\log{c}$$

Simplifying,

$$\frac{1}{2}\log{\left(\left|\frac{v-1}{(v+1)^3}\right|\right)}=\log{(|cx|)}$$

Further simplification will give us
$$\frac{v-1}{(v+1)^3}={(cx)}^2$$

Here  $\log$ denotes the logarithmic function to the base $e$.

Answer (score 0):

Solutions found from

$$\int\frac{g'(y))\,dy}{g(y)}=\int\frac{f'(x))\,dy}{f(x)}\implies \log|g(y)|=\log|f(x)|+c$$

are equivalent to

$$g(y)=\pm e^c f(x).$$

But as $c$ is arbitrary, this is also expressed by

$$g(y)=cf(x).$$

---

Notice that in the event that $g(y)=0$ or $f(x)=0$ somewhere, we have a singularity, which cannot be crossed. This means that the solution can be made of several pieces, with different integration constants.